# AngularJS's `$location.path()` is not changed when I click BACK button of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, window, video.js

I was using videoJS to load video dynamically, and want to destroy the video player when `route` or `location` changes, I tried to wrap it in a directive like this (Coffeescript code):

```
angular.module('myModule')
.directive('myDirective', ($location)->
  return {
  restrict: 'A'
  scope: {rawUrl: '='}
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->    
    attrs.type = 'application/x-mpegURL'
    setup =
      controls: true
      preload: 'auto'
      autoplay: true
      height: window.innerHeight
      width: window.innerWidth
      'data-setup': '{example_option: true}'

    myPlayer = element

    scope.$watch('location.path()', ->
      # TODO: destroy videoJS when user leaves video page
      console.log($location.path())
      if not $location.path().match '/video/'
        console.log("destroy you!")
        videojs(attrs.id).dispose()

    )
    scope.$watch('rawUrl.videoUrl', (newvalue)->
      if newvalue
        player = videojs(attrs.id, setup, ->
          console.log('created')
          this.src(newvalue)
          return
        )
        videojs(attrs.id).ready( ->
          console.log('ready!')
          myPlayer = this
          aspectRatio = 9 / 16;
          resizeVideoJS = ->
            myPlayer.width(window.innerWidth).height(window.innerHeight);            )


   )
  }
)
```

However, I found the callback function within `scope.$watch('location.path(), mycallback)` is not called if I changed the page using broswer's BACK button..

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `scope.$on('$destroy', destroyCallback)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but you could try to wrap the $location.path() call inside of a function defined on the scope e.g.

`scope.location = { 
     path : function () { return $location.path(); }
 }`

Again, I'm not sure if the route change will occur prior to the digest cycle.

If it does, you could, instead, listen for the location-change event ([Angular doc on $location events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)) using:

`scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
     /* code you had in your watcher should still work fine here */
});`

**Edit:** Editing $route events to $location events (refer to new link in documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular). $location events should be broadcasted upon changes in the browser's url.