# Create custom browser back action the Angular way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-experience

I am using angularJS in my SPA. I want to disable the default action of browser back button/android back button in my webapp and create custom actions for the same.

**Example case**: I have a signup page where user entries are saved as scope variables before submitting the form. An amazing fullscreen form lets user select the location, having a back button to hide the form (just in case). As a bad UX, whenever the user presses back button in mobile or browser, page is redirected to previous page in *location.history*. Also, *location.history.forward()* method reinitializes the controller, thus having user to fill everything again.

What could be the best possible working solution in given constraints?

*No external libraries please*

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you
[Control or Disable Browser Back Button with Javascript or AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345481/control-or-disable-browser-back-button-with-javascript-or-angularjs)

or

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) { window.history.forward(1); }
```

When the history detects the first history.back()

```
window.onpopstate
```

Comment: On history.forward(), the controllers would be reinitialized. I wouldn't find it to be the most ideal way. *I have found something alien in the $routeProvider documentation - reloadOnSearch property.* Digging about it. Will update if that works. Thanks for help!

Update: never mind the italics, misinterpreted in first read!! Duh!!