# How to disable Back button of Browsers in SPA apps With Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla, back-button-control

In my single page application developed using **Angular Js**, I don't want to navigate in browser using browsers **Back button**,**How to Hide or Disable or override the Back button function**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control browser features using Javascript. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here. But this code above will not work well with AngularJS because AngularJS uses URL_Hash # in the background.

[Control or Disable Browser Back Button with Javascript or AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345481/control-or-disable-browser-back-button-with-javascript-or-angularjs)