# How to prevent navigation from one state to another state in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to intercept when user clicks on browser back button from a specific view to navigate it to home view rather than the default back page. Any ideas on how to do this?

I have states defined as below. I can't allow to navigate from the state 'paymentsubmitted' to 'payment'

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/' ,
            templateUrl: 'search',
            controller: 'payCtrl'
        })
        .state('details', {
            url: '/details/{id:int}',
            templateUrl: 'details',
            controller: 'payDetailsCtrl'
        })
        .state('payment', {
            url: '/payment',
            templateUrl: 'Payment',
            controller: 'payPaymentCtrl'
        })
        .state('paymentsubmitted', {
            url: '/paymentsubmitted',
            templateUrl: 'PaymentSubmitted',
            controller: 'payPaymentCtrl'
        });
```

I tried to use $locationChangeStart but next and current are looking at absolute urls. How can I have it look at the states that are defined? Thank you!

```
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (current == '') {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried using $routeChangeStart ? Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs).

Comment: `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
})` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: Thank you. It is working with $stateChangeStart.