# Browser back button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have menu links. on clicking on these menu links hiding using angularjs. 
How to enable browser back button to navigate back.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement history.back() in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070285/how-to-implement-history-back-in-angular-js)

Comment: Please see this discussions [How to detect(How to enable) if a user clicks browser back button in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs)