# how to detect whether back button was pressed or not in an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

i want to do something like this in an angular directive function:

```
    app.directive("detectFocus", function ($focusTest, $location, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            onBlur: '&onBlur',
        },
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            elem.on("blur", function () {  
                console.log("blur");
                if(back button is pressed) {
                    $focusTest.setFocusOnBlur(false);
                }
                else {
                    $focusTest.setFocusOnBlur(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How can i detect whether back button was pressed or not....

Comment: [ngBlur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a `$rootScope` variable to check whether the `backbutton` is pressed or not.

```
$rootScope.navigated = false;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
    if (from.name) { $rootScope.navigated = true; }
});
```

Then inside your `link` function, you can do something like this

```
link: function(scope, elem) {
    elem.on("blur", function() {
        console.log("blur");
        if ($rootScope.navigated) {
            $focusTest.setFocusOnBlur(false);
        } else {
            $focusTest.setFocusOnBlur(true);
        }
    });
}
```