# How to capture the browser back button event in angularjs1?

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement my piece of code on click of a browser back button and a back link on right click of a mouse.

Kindly help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a user clicks browser back button in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

`window.onbeforeunload = function() { //dosomething(); 
                                     };`

Comment: This didnot work for me.It dint not work for browser back button click

Comment: @durga Please note that `onbeforeunload` event is also fired when F5 or Forward buttons are pushed because that's when the current page is unloaded.

Comment: will this also trigger when the user click on a browser back button??

Comment: Try @Saurabh Agrawal link on your question

Comment: Could anyone give us the solution for the same?