# AngularJS browser back button detection on a form

Tags: angularjs

I have a form page, that a user will use to insert a certain value on the database.

What I want to do is, detect if the user clicked the back button on the browser and show a modal asking if he wants to continue filling the form or really go back.

Can this be done with AngularJS?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs

Comment: @james00794 State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hook `OnExit` of the UI-Router. That hook is invoked when a state is being exited:

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'your-state',
  onExit: ['MyService', function (MyService) {
    return MyService.openModal();
  }]
});
```

Here, on the [official documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#onexit) you can find more details about how this works.

Keep rocking!

Comment: Unfortunately this won't do the trick because I have many child states that make up the form. And a parent state that directs to these child states. So if I use onExit, the popup will show everytime the user changes the "sub-form".

Comment: I understand your problem. Other option can be fire the modal when the mouse leaves the window