# Browser back button going to application page after logout

Tags: angularjs

I have logout button in my angularjs(1.5) application. On click of it calling the login page url.After logout, when i click the browser back button again it is going to my application page instead of login page.

```
    $scope.logOutUser = function () {
            $window.location.href = "logoutURL";
        }
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement this in angularjs?

Comment: `angular.run` handles transitions, you can listed for onStart event and check if you are logged off, then you should be redirected to "login page"

Comment: Use `$location.replace()` after the statement i.e. `$window.location.href = "logoutURL";$location.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

*Use* `$location` service's [`.replace()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#replace-method) method

```
$scope.logOutUser = function () {
    $window.location.href = "logoutURL";
    $location.replace()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take this my old post abut the back button issue : [How to detect if a user clicks browser back button in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901409/how-to-detect-if-a-user-clicks-browser-back-button-in-angularjs/29901473#29901473)

You may may need that logic like

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (scope, next, current) {
        if (next.$$route.controller != "Your dashboard Controller Name") {// please be mine dash board controller is your home page after login
            // Show here for your model, and do what you need**
            $window.location.href = "logoutURL";
        }
    });
```

But if you did logout in dashboard page then it would be an issue. At this time you need to maintain a flag with [ng-Storage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) for the user is currently authenticate or not.

Comment: you shouldn't use private identifiers with `$$` prefix