# Angular UI Router Reload Controller on Back Button Press

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-routing

I have a route that can have numerous optional query parameters:

```
$stateProvider.state("directory.search", {
                url: '/directory/search?name&email',
                templateUrl: 'view.html',
                controller: 'controller'
```

When the user fills the form to search the directory a function in the `$scope` changes the state causing the controller to reload:

```
 $scope.searchDirectory = function () {
            $state.go('directory.search', {
                name: $scope.Model.Query.name,
                email: $scope.Model.Query.email
            }, { reload: true });                   
        };
```

In the `controller` I have a conditional: `if($state.params){return data}` dictating whether or not my service will be queried.

This works great except if the user clicks the brower's forward and/or back buttons. In both these cases the state (route) changes the query parameters correctly but does not reload the `controller`.

From what I've read the controller will be reloaded only if the actual route changes. Is there anyway to make this example work only using query parameters or must I use a changing route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should listen to the event for succesful page changes, $locationChangeSuccess. Checkout the docs for it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location.

There is also a similar question answered on so here [How to detect browser back button click event using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular).

When that event fires you could put whatever logic you run on pageload that you need to run when the controller initializes.

Something like:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.searchDirectory()
});
```

Or better setup like:

```
var searchDirectory = function () {
    $state.go('directory.search', {
        name: $scope.Model.Query.name,
        email: $scope.Model.Query.email
    }, { reload: true });

$scope.searchDirectory = searchDirectory;

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
    searchDirectory();
});
```

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution using the links you posted. My answer is below. It seems peculiar that the `$locationChangeSuccess` event and the `$rootScope.$watch` placed on `$location.absUrl()` was firing multiple times. See comments and conditional within the `$rootScope.$watch` call.

Answer (score 1):

Using the above, I was able to come up with a solution to my issue:

controller (code snippet):

```
...var searchDirectory = function (searchParams) {

            if (searchParams) {
                $scope.Model.Query.name = searchParams.name;
                $scope.Model.Query.email = searchParams.email;
            }

            $state.go('directory.search', {
                name: $scope.Model.Query.name,
                email: $scope.Model.Query.email,
            }, { reload: true });                   
        };...

       $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            //used $location.absUrl() to keep track of query string
            //could have used $location.path() if just interested in the portion of the route before query string params
            $rootScope.actualLocation = $location.absUrl(); 
        });

        $rootScope.$watch(function () { return $location.absUrl(); }, function (newLocation, oldLocation) {
            //event fires too often? 
            //before complex conditional was used the state was being changed too many times causing a saturation of my service
            if ($rootScope.actualLocation && $rootScope.actualLocation !== oldLocation && oldLocation !== newLocation) {
                searchDirectory($location.search());
            }
        });

        $scope.searchDirectory = searchDirectory;

 if ($state.params && Object.keys($state.params).length !== 0)
{..call to service getting data...}
```

This solution feels more like a traditional framework such as .net web forms where the dev has to perform certain actions based on the state of the page. I think it's worth the compromise of having readable query params in the URL.