# AngularJS Detect browser back button press in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am making a browser trivia game and I have a view where a authenticated player selects a game type, which emits a socket.io event to be handled by my Node.js server, then changes the path to a "Searching for game" screen with a loading icon as the server waits enough people to join a matchmaking queue.  I put a "Cancel" button on this page, which will emit another socket.io event to my server to remove the user from the matchmaking queue.

Now here is the problem, if the user presses the back button in their browser, the Cancel button is not pressed so the cancelSearch() function is not called, and therefore the socket.io emit is not sent to the server to remove the user from the search queue.  Here is the relevant code...I believe I will have to add some code to my matchsearchCtrl.js file to be able to handle a back button press and call cancelSearch() accordingly..

**playgame.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Select your Game Type!</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="startMatchMaking()">1v1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="startMatchMaking()">2v2</button>
</div>
```

**playgameCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('playgameCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $uibModal, socket, $location) {

    $scope.startMatchMaking = function() {
        socket.emit('joinMatchMaking', $rootScope.user.username);
        $location.path('/searching');
    }

});
```

**matchsearch.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Searching for players...</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-large" ng-click="cancelSearch()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**matchsearchCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('matchsearchCtrl', function($scope, $location, socket) {

    $scope.cancelSearch = function() {
        socket.emit('leaveMatchMaking', $rootScope.user.username);
        $location.path('/home');
    }
})
```

And if this is needed...

**app.routes.js**

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: './app/views/landingpage.html',
        controller: 'landingpageCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: './app/views/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/play', {
        templateUrl: './app/views/playgame.html',
        controller: 'playgameCtrl'
    })
    .when('/searching', {
        templateUrl: './app/views/matchsearch.html',
        controller: 'matchsearchCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise('/');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript `window.onbeforeunload` not only to detect the back button  but if the user leave the page, closing the window, for example.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    //Do your stuff here
}
```

---

## Edit

Use `$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(){//Do your stuff here});` to detect the page change.

Comment: it is better to inject `$window` into the controller and use it instead of `window`.

Comment: So I will put this in my matchsearchCtrl.js file, and call cancelSearch() in the Do your stuff here line...and see if it works in a second

Comment: @Amir Thanks, I was going to ask if I should inject $window.  Does it matter though?

Comment: Your code would be more testable if you inject `$window`. Angular can mock the object for testing and track the functions you call on `$window`. And it is a good practice to use it. In future if they update the framework, you'll benefit from new features.

Comment: @Amir is right. My anwser is in pure JS. As you are using Angular i think you should follow his suggestion.

Comment: @Amir I appreciate your insight, I am testing the OP's method right now, but am using $window instead as you suggested.

Comment: @Amir So I just injected $window into matchsearchCtrl, and added this to that file, and the alert did not show when I pressed the back button.. $window.onbeforeunload = function() {
     alert("back button pressed");
     $scope.cancelSearch();
 }

Comment: I would not suggest to touch `$window`. If you are using `ng-router` or `ui-router` there are other events you can listen on. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063490/angular-ui-router-reload-controller-on-back-button-press

Comment: Ok, I also saw this solution (it uses $rootscope.$watch), but in it the callback is called on every back button press app wide, I only want it to be called when the matchsearch.html view is on the users screen.  Anyways I'll look into what you posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular

Comment: Anyways thanks for trying guys, I'll figure this out and probably end up answering my own question down the line.  Obviously I am a bit of a noob still :)  But would be nice if I could just handle the window.onbeforeunload event like the OP suggested.

Comment: I checked one of my projects and i was using ` $scope.$on("$locationChangeStart",function(){//});` instead of `window.onbeforeunload`. The same as the cited post, but using `$scope`instead of `$rootScope`

Comment: @marcosspn Trying it now.

Comment: @marcosspn Well, it does indeed work when the back button is pressed, but it also fires for any location.path change, even non back button presses.  I think I will need some sort of flag variable or something along those lines, but what you posted is pretty close to what I'm looking for

Comment: Ok. I'll change my anwser because `window.onbeforeunload` seems to be a wrong answer.