# Where am I in the history list?

Tags: javascript, browser

My goal here is to create a Javascript function in a one-page app that can tell me if the back-button would do anything.

I thought that `window.history.length` would help me: if the length is same as when the app started, you are at "the beginning" and the function should do nothing.

But no. Imagine that there is one internal link in the app, `#a`.  When you start the app from a new tab, the browser is at `#`, the length is 1 and you know the back button will do nothing.  If you click the `#a`, you go to `#a`, the length is 2, and you know the back button would work.

Then, sadly, if you do press the back button, you go back to `#`, but the length is still 2, because `#a` is in the "future history".

Help me out.  How do I know whether the back button is currently "active"?  This is killing me.

(The problem is a little complicated by the idea that there might be a URL from a completely different site in the history.  For me, that should be treated as "inactive", even though the back-button would itself actually work.)

Comment: what framework are you using for your single page app?

Comment: Angular, but it doesn't matter.  How is this done at all?

Comment: see my answer for using $locationChangeSuccess in angular

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your users never modify the url manually, then the only ways they navigate are by either

- Pressing a button/link in your app, or
- Pressing the back button

Therefor, you can track this with your own history. Every time a button is clicked, store what page it was on and that a button was clicked (possibly in localstorage). Then, when it loads again you can simply test whether or not where the user is now was reached by hitting a button/link or hitting back. If it was by hitting back, decrement your history. If you have no recorded history, you know the back button either won't work or goes to a different site.

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying to get this working for two months now.  Among other problems: the reload button.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to store route changes within your app and keep your own state history. This is because of the following:

> For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the
>   non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session
>   history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history.

To do this in angular you need to use the $locationChangeSuccess event. See: [How to detect browser back button click event using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular) for detecting back button and if its not back button simply append to an array that you track.