# Getting incorrect states while click of back button on browser in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

i have an angular js application using different states , my first page is login page and it contains a forgot password link , on the click of forgot pwd the app will redirect onto forgot pwd page , after succesfull login a dashboard gets appeared the scenarios are:

when i am on login page and click browsers back button i will be redirected onto login page only .

when i am on forgot pwd page and click back button i will be redirected onto login page , as it is the first page of my application.

the problem i am facing here is when i reload my forgot password page and click on browsers back button i gets redirected onto login page and again click on back button the app gets redirected to dashboard without even login into the application , i am not getting where i am going wrong in putting my states. kindly help

here is my router.js inside app module,
here default route means dashboard

```
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'DEFAULT_ROUTE', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, DEFAULT_ROUTE) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(DEFAULT_ROUTE);
      // application start point
      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: '',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: 'src/app/templates/base.html',
          controller: 'AppController'
        });

    }])

    .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth', 'DEFAULT_ROUTE', function($rootScope, $location, Auth, DEFAULT_ROUTE){
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if(!Auth.session() && $location.path() != '/forgot'){
          $location.path('/login');
        } else {

          if($location.path() == '/login') {
              //$location.path(DEFAULT_ROUTE);
              $location.path('/login');
            }
          else if($location.path()=='/forgot'){
              $location.path('/forgot');
            }
        }
      });
    }])
```

here is my routing for login module:

```
config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider){
      $stateProvider
        .state('app.login', {
          url: '/login',
          views: {
            "content": {
              templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/login.html',
              controller: 'loginController'
            }
          }
        })
          .state('app.forgotPassword', {
              url: '/forgot',
              views: {
                  "content": {
                      templateUrl: 'src/login/templates/forgotPassword.html',
                      controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
                  }
              }
          })
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

do you keep session information? in cookies or other form? if yes do following

```
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var token = $cookieStore.get('token');           
         if(token==null)          

           $location.path('/');

 });
```

Comment: i have an Auth service which stores the data into local storage but it is done only after login .

Answer (score 0):

So basically you needs to detect from which page the state has changed and than you can achive your redirect criteria. You can achive it by using **$locationChangeSuccess**.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular) for more information.If you can add the plunker replicating your scenario than we would help you much by adding missing part in it.