# Detect Forward and Backward Routes througth a Button - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-click

Plenty of folks have asked how to detect *back* button clicks/gestures in AngularJS but that is really only half of the equation.

In order to use `ngAnimate` transitions, specifically a slide left on forward and a slide right on back, I need to *detect both forward and backward* history events.

Detecting back seems to trigger, on forward does as well, since URLs' behavior is very similar on both actions.

I would have just asked more about this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20038350/1288913), but I don't have enough reputation to make that.

Previous answer does not seem to work for me on Angular 1.4.7.

How do I detect both forward and backward events in AngularJS?

Comment: Do you mean how to set up your routing stuff when clicking on "forward" and "back"?

Comment: You can use events like `stateChangeStart` or `stateChangeSuccess`