# How to reload current state of page in angularJs when Browser back button is pressed?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, back-button

I am facing a problem in detecting when the browser's back button is clicked. My code doesn't detect the event:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
  $rootScope.previousState = from;
  $rootScope.previousStateParams = fromParams;
});
```

I think this is happening because my previous view is the same as current view. I can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is an $state method called reload. -> api ui-router

$state.reload('example.whatever'); Maybe this can help you.

Comment: But there must be some event generation should happen, so that i can call $stat.reload().In my case it is not happening

Comment: I mean when I am clicking on back button my state is not getting changed since I am on same state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular like this?

Answer (score 0):

event **$stateChangeStart**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', ...
```

> Fired when the state transition begins. You can use
>   event.preventDefault() to prevent the transition from happening and
>   then the transition promise will be rejected with a 'transition
>   prevented' value.

[ui router api](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Comment: I tried this also , not working for , event is not detecting

Comment: check if you referenced the ui-router.js in you index file, and also add the 'ui.router' into you angular.module