# How to detect browser back before view variables are loaded in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to detect the user pressing the back button in AngularJS, and have found the following solution very useful: [How to detect browser back button click event using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular)

However, when implementing the code, and then using Chrome's breakpointing on the JS, I find that in between the `$locationChangeSuccess` and `$watch` functions, the previous view's angular code is being run, as I put `console.log()` functions on the controller code (which are outputting before the `console.log()` functions in the `$watch` function).

I need to be able to catch the 'back button' trigger BEFORE the view code runs, so that I can reset/change the data in the controller before the view tries to make use of it.

By view code, I mean variables and functions called by `{{myFunction()}}` and `{{myVariable}}` in the HTML code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edits. Bit odd on the title edits, one of you decides angularJS shouldnt be in the title, the other adds it back in :P In the topic note, as I am using Ionic as well, I have ended up using their `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` function, which works a treat and fires at the right time. I do however hope someone will have a solution to the Angular only situation without Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com) based solution, if Ionic is being used**

I know the following answer won't address the *exact* original question, but based on the lack of responses; I either did not ask a good question, no-one knows the angular based answer, or there is currently no solution.

So for those who happen to use Ionic and angular, I have found a solution:

As I am using Ionic as well, I have ended up using their `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction()` function, which works a treat and fires at the right time. I do however hope someone will have a solution to the Angular only situation without Ionic.

**Further reading**

- [Ionic Documentation for `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/)
- [Ionic framework: Handling android back button like a pro](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-handling-android-back-button-like-a-pro/)