# AngularJS - Success Callback for $window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

In my app, it programatically goes back with a back button to the previous url. Here is what I do:

```
$window.history.back();
```

Now, after changing to the previous url (controller/template completely loaded), I want to execute some code. How do I listen to the success of $window.history.back()? I want to achieve that it scrolls to the exact same position as before. I need to do this because I want scroll generally on top with event `$stateChangeSuccess` but if sb. goes back with back-button it should go back to the scroll position (normal list-detail-view --> if sb goes to detail view and goes back to list the scroll position should be the same as before). Unfortunately [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/detect-history-back-using-angular) does not work as it is called before the complete controller/view is loaded.

EDIT

My plan is as follows. In run-function:

```
var lastScrollPosition = 0;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    lastScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 0);
});

$rootScope.backButton = function() {
    $window.history.back().then(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: lastScrollPosition
        }, 0);
    });
};
```

So if the state changed the scroll position is saved, that works. And if a back button is pressed it calls `backButton`-Function. After the `$window.history.back()`-Command is executed I want to call a Success-Function and jump to the saved scroll position --> tbd how this functionality could be achieved.

Comment: How does the application remember the scroll position? An idea that comes to mind is a listener for the scroll event that sets a query param in the URL with the actual scroll position. The route controller must now honour the scroll position from the URL, if any.

Comment: That is a really good idea but I prefer to not add sth to url as the url should stay readable/beautiful. I updated my answer how my plan is right now.

Comment: You want to handle the case of the user pressing the brower's built-in back button too, right?

Comment: Hmmm, the `lastScrollPosition` cannot be a singleton as it is in the "plan" code. Imagine this: you navigate to the results (instance A), scroll to 50px, navigate away, navigate to the results anew (instance B) scroll to 100px, navigate away. Then press BACK until you reach instance A. With the planned code, the scroll will be set to 100px, the value for instance B. If you do not want to pollute the URL, you should have a stack (?) of remembered scroll positions and take care to sync it with the history (e.g. what about `history.go(-3)`).

Comment: @yscik yep would be better.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos you are right would be better if it is easily possible. I thought it would be ok if I navigate away and come back (I have tabs) than it is okay if scroll position is 0 again. But if it is not too heavily to do than would be great of course to have a stack with scrollPositions and save it for every URL!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to approach this from the other way around: have the scroll position restoration as the default behaviour on $stateChangeSuccess (with a map of last scroll positions assigned to every state, updated on $stateChangeStart), and handle the user clicks a link cases separately, since you have more control over those.

Replace any `ui-sref` with an `ng-click='go(state, params)'`, having a global `go` function which just flips a flag indicating that you will want to scroll to the top in the $stateChangeSuccess callback.

```
var scrollPositions = {};

$rootScope.go = function gotoState(state, params, options) {
   $rootScope.scroll_to_top = true;
   $state.go(state, params, options);
}

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: !$rootScope.scroll_to_top && scrollPositions[toState] || 0
    }, 0);
    $rootScope.scroll_to_top = false;
});


$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    scrollPositions[fromState] =  $(window).scrollTop();
    });
```

Comment: I like the idea but it does not work. Btw you have 2 syntax errors in your code (line 10 should not end with semicolon, delete line 17).
It does not work because $stateChangeSuccess is called before the complete `toState`-View is rendered

Comment: Indeed you have to wait for the rendering to finish, try the `$viewContentLoaded` event or a small `$timeout`. If you have content to load and want to adjust the scroll positioning after that, you could emit a custom event in each controller after it fetched and set up all data that affects the layout.

Comment: I don't want use `timeout`, I asked for a `Success Callback` and timeout is the poorest answer. I tried it but it always calls the scrolltop before view is rendered, that is bullshit. Could not imagine that there is a nice solution for that, how to other people handle that?

Comment: Then try the other solutions I suggested in the comment. Only you can know what content needs to be loaded for a page to be considered done, so you will probably need to go with emitting an event in each controller. Also, please update your question if this is the problem you are trying to solve, as it has no relation to history.back calls and differentating them from link-initatied state changes.

Comment: I already tried but as I sad it is always called before the complete view is build/rendered. I will try another approach and let you know if that worked. My question is for a success function (complete controller/view loaded) of history back so that is definetely what I need and that is stated in my question