# Check whether ui-state has forward ui-state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I think it is a simple question but could not find on google. I am using angular 1.5 and ui-router 1.5. How do I check if current ui-view state had next ui-state? (This is required because I want to check whether current ui-view is loaded when back button is pressed or through direct link)

```
Case 1
--------
view1 -> view2 -> view3 // now I have pressed back button 
view1 -> view2 ? // Here view2 actually had next state that was view3

Case 2
--------
view1 -> view4 -> view2 //Here view2 do not have next ui-state
```

I have tried using `$ionicHistory.forwardView()` but it always return null. Not sure why? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any logical way to figure out some views are child views of a particular view (say view2)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser back button click event using angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-click-event-using-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling for 4 hours I have come up with some custom solution. would like to share. Proper error handling has to be done yet.

```
// just listen to statechange success event 
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
      function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
        // if fromState.name is empty, its refresh || first landing
        var history = $window.localStorage.getItem('history');
        var back = false;
        if (history !== null) {
            history = JSON.parse(history);
            if (toState.name === history.from && fromState.name === history.to) {
                back = true;
            }
        }
        $window.localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify({
            to: toState.name,
            from: fromState.name,
            isBack: back
       }));
   });
});
```

**Note** I have used persistent storage technique. One must handle refresh condition also.