# ui router back button issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing, frontend

i am working on web app that uses ui-router version 0.3.2 and angular 1.5. i am having an issue with back button, when i hit the back button the url updates to appropriate state url, but does not reloads / renders the page. The controller of the new state (updated url) does not get executed. Following is my state config

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  templateUrl: 'homePage.html',
  controller:'homeController'
})
.state('home.overView', {
  url:'overView',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  views: {
    ovSB: {
      templateUrl: 'searchParameterBarTemplate.html',
      controller: 'searchParameterBarController'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.overView.result', {
  url:'/:docType?abc&xyz&type&user&temp1&temp2',
  abstract: true,
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  templateUrl: 'resultViewTemplate.html',
  controller : 'resultPanelController'
})
.state('home.overView.result.dashboard', {
  url:'',
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  views: {
    'chart': {
      templateUrl: 'chart-template.html',
      controller: 'chart-Controller'
    },
    'oVGrid': {
      templateUrl: 'ov-grid-template.html',
      controller: 'ov-grid-controller'
    },
    'filterGrid': {
      templateUrl: 'filter-stats-template.html',
      controller: 'filter-stats-controller'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.delta',{
  reloadOnSearch: false,
  url:'Delta',

  views:{
    pcSB:{
      templateUrl: 'search-parameterbar-delta-template.html',
      controller : 'search-parameterBar-delta-controller'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.delta.result',{
  url:'/:docType?xyz_1&abc_1&xyz_2&abc_2',

  reloadOnSearch: false,
  templateUrl: 'delta-template.html',
  controller : 'delta-controller'
})
.state('home.details', {
  url: 'details',

  views: {
    detailsSB: {
      templateUrl: 'search-paramBar-details-template.html',
      controller: 'search-paramBar-details-controller'
    }
  }
})
.state('home.details.result', {
  url: '/:documentType?abc&xyz&user&temp1&temp2',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'details-view-template.html',
  controller: 'details-view-controller'
})
.state('home.details.result.dashboard',{
  url:'',
  views:{
    perGraph : {
      controller :'per-graph-controller',
      templateUrl: 'per-graph-template.html'
    },
    detailsGrid: {
      controller: 'details-grid-controller',
      templateUrl: 'details-grid-controller-template.html'
    }
  }
});
```

So for example if i navigate from home.overview.result.dashboard (url -> ***localhost:12345/overview/doctype?abc&xyz&user&temp1&temp2***) state to home.details.result.dashboard state with url ***localhost:12345/details/doctype?abc&xyz&user&temp1&temp2*** and hit backbutton, the url updates to ***localhost:12345/overview/doctype?abc&xyz&user&temp1&temp2*** however it does not reloads/renders the page.

I believe I can you use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813850/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-click-event-using-angular) and trigger the reload, but I am looking for a better solution than this which adheres to ui router. is there something i am missing with state config / doing wrong? Any help pertaining to this would be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: try removing reloadOnSearch from your 'home' state

Comment: tried that, didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

it will be firing $stateChangeStart event. use location directive to rout it . please refer the below snippet

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event,next) { 
    $location.path(next.$$route.originalPath);
});
```

this can resolve your problem. but its not the perfect solution